# Significance comparison in ggplot not working with verbatim identical annotation entries

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot significance differences using `ggsignif::geom_signif()` but run into issues if the significance description is identical for multiple comparisons.

Consider the following toy data set:

```
structure(list(x = c("a1", "a2", "b3", "b4", "c5", "c6"), 
               treat = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1), 
               group = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c"), 
               fit = c(72, 80, 55, 59, 51, 65),
               lwr = c(67, 71, 51, 52, 45, 52),
               upr = c(76, 89, 58, 66, 57, 78)), 
               row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Suppose this is loaded as `df`, I create a plot using:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=fit, color=group)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=lwr, ymax=upr), width=.09, position=position_dodge(.25)) +
  ggsignif::geom_signif(data = data.frame(x = c("x", "a2", "b3")),
                        aes(y_position = c(  95, 75, 80),
                            xmin       = c(   1,  3,  5),
                            xmax       = c(   2,  4,  6),
                            annotations= c( "*","n.s",  "n.s.")), # only one displayed if verbatim identical
                        color      = "black",
                        tip_length=0.01, manual = T) +
  ylim(0, 100) + 
  ggthemes::theme_base()
```

The plot looks as follows:

[image: plot2]

Note that the comparisons say "n.s" and "n.s." (one with a `.` after the `s` and one without). If I include `annotations=c("*", "n.s.", "n.s.")` (i.e. two identical elements), the plot looks like this:

[image: plot2]

How do I get the first plot with identical annotation texts (i.e. `n.s.` and `n.s.` instead of `n.s.` and `n.s`) with both displayed?

**EDIT** I would like the display to be declared in the function (and not adding manually to the values of `annotations` since they are in the original code coming from a function call and are declared variables).

Answer (score 0):

You could give one annotation an extra whitespace to make it different like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=fit, color=group)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=lwr, ymax=upr), width=.09, position=position_dodge(.25)) +
  ggsignif::geom_signif(data = data.frame(x = c("x", "a2", "b3")),
                        aes(y_position = c(  95, 75, 80),
                            xmin       = c(   1,  3,  5),
                            xmax       = c(   2,  4,  6),
                            annotations= c( "*"," n.s.",  "n.s.")), # only one displayed if verbatim identical
                        color      = "black",
                        tip_length=0.01, manual = T) +
  ylim(0, 100) + 
  ggthemes::theme_base()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you. So far, that was my workaround - but I'm using functions to test significance levels, so it's very bothersome to manually add white spaces for the comparisons to be displayed separately, which is why I'm looking for a way to force separate displays as part of the call.